# Symfony4 Can't modify FOSUser button with bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony4

I would like to modify the submit button from the register FOSUser form in order to use the btn btn-primary from bootstrap 4.

But I can't succeed.

There he is:

```
<div class="fos_registration_row">
    <div class="fos_registration_label"></div>
    <div class="fos_registration_input">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">S'enregistrer</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is all the custom css I've added

```
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.fos_registration{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(blue, white);
    width:50%;
}

.fos_registration_title{
    text-align: center;
}

.fos_registration_row{
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.fos_registration_label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

.fos_registration_input{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

input{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have

[image: register page screen]

Please do not hesitate asking me for more information if you think it can help. I'm pretty newbie with CSS, so I might have forgot important stuff

EDIT:

Here is my package.json so as you can check bootstrap is well installed.

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
        "jquery.js": "^0.0.2-security",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post your # app/config/config.yml
to your Twig Configuration

Comment: @hoover_D there isn't any app folder in Symfony4.  If you are speaking about twig.yaml then, there it is. `twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
`